# init 0 process is not starting

Tags: ubuntu, kernel, initramfs

Yesterday I have encountered one problem, when I turn on my PC it took a long time to boot. After booting it reached to `command line` with `<initramfs>` (It is unknown to me what it is)

I thought it is some asking for `GUI` so I typed `exit` and `ENTER`. Here it comes a big issue now, It displayed one message

> Attempted to kill process `init0`(and some more)

After that it displayed stack trace where some kernel messages printed (I am not able to copy all those messages). It seems like a problem to me so I just `restarted` my PC. Now my PC is not booting at all.

Can someone please help me to fix this and explain me what I have done wrong?

Comment: Speculation: hardware failure. If I'm right, this isn't the right forum for the question. Try booting with the OS install medium, and use the "rescue" mode. If that works, it probably isn't the hardware, unless it's the hard disk.

Comment: @WarrenYoung... Could you please explain some more. In rescue mode what I need to do, or it will work automatically.

Comment: I speculate it's hardware failure partly because *ix boxes generally don't stop booting all by themselves, and partly because two successive reboot attempts give different results. That suggests something outside the OS is having trouble. The point of the rescue mode test is that it lets you load your OS from a known-good boot setup, the one on the install medium. If you can see your files when in rescue mode, the HDD may be okay, and you'll have to look elsewhere for the problem. But if rescue mode fails, too, you might have CPU or RAM problems.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of initramfs is explained at [wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initramfs).

It is usually (after the bios) the first booting step responsible of mounting the boot media and things like that.

Typing `exit` will exit the boot process, but will to do any permanent harm to your system. The question is, why you got that prompt. This usually only happens, when there are critical problems. In this case there should have been a message telling you what the problem was.

What exactly do you mean by "does not boot at all"? Is there some kind of error message?

Probably the best way is booting from some kind of live CD and backup any important data.

Comment: Actually I installed ubuntu server in VmWare. after that my system performance affected. Thanks for advice, I already kept my data safe. "Does not boot at all" means always it is hanging before login page.

Comment: There are a couple of steps before the login page. (bios, bootloader(like grub), initramfs, init, etc.) Did you get any output at all? are you able to get in the bootloader?

Comment: Yes, bootloader is fine

Comment: Is there any output, after the bootloader? you can also use the bootloader to change you boot option, remove any splash features, add something like `verbose` to get more output, try something like `init=/bin/bash` to see if the problem is before or after init. - How to fix it really depends on the result. - If it is really a VM without any important data, then maybe it is easier to set it up from scratch. ;)

Comment: Thanks michas... I`ll check this. I am not able to copy exact output from there, and this is the only problem. Today I`ll try to update my question with original output then may be you can give me exact answer.Actually I have installed two linux 1) is desktop for my use and 2) is server which is in VM. so problem is with my desktop, not with VM. Give me some time to update my question.